# Error in opening a pre-filled realm db in react-native app - TypeError: undefined is not a function in asyncGeneratorStep

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm trying to develop an app as my hobby project using React Native + realm DB.
I just want to connect to **pre-filled realm DB** (sitting inside app-bundle) and do some CRUD ops using view controls.

I've followed the steps in the react-native realm docs, however, I'm facing a strange issue while executing following code.

```
export async function checkDBFn(): Promise<boolean> {
  let bundlePath = RNFS.MainBundlePath + '/OlamDB.realm';
  const exists = await RNFS.exists(bundlePath);

  if (exists) {
    try {
      Realm.open({
        path: bundlePath,
        schema: [DBSchema],
        schemaVersion: 5,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof Error) {
        let error = e as Error;
        console.log(exists, error.message, e.name, e.stack);
        // prints true,  undefined is not a function, TypeError, and error stack
    }
    
  return exists

}
```

Getting this error stack:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at ?anon_0_ (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:174245:21)
    at next (native)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:21697:26)
    at _next (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:21716:29)
    at tryCallOne (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:53:16)
    at anonymous (/Users/distiller/react-native/sdks/hermes/build_iphonesimulator/lib/InternalBytecode/InternalBytecode.js:139:27)
    at apply (native)
    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:27425:26)
    at _callTimer (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:27340:17)
    at _callReactNativeMicrotasksPass (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:27373:17)
    at callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:27537:44)
    at __callReactNativeMicrotasks (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:2485:46)
    at anonymous (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:2285:45)
    at __guard (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:2465:15)
    at flushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:2284:21)
    at invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true&app=org.reactjs.native.example.MyApp:2278:33)
```

Initially I thought it as a ployfill issue and I've tried to [solve this issue by adding core-js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18542) polyfill and importing symbol and iterator, but no luck(actually I got another error, not yet solved :) ).

```
import 'core-js/stable/symbol';
import 'core-js/stable/symbol/iterator';
```

Without **realm.open()** code, application code works fine. I've tested the pre-filled DB with NodeJS code and its working perfectly.

**Environment:**

**Deps:**
"core-js": "^3.26.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.3",
"react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
"realm": "^11.0.0"

**OS:** macOS Monterey 12.6 , **NodeJS** 16.x , **Xcode** 14.0.1

Could you please help me on this. I truly appreciate any suggestions or comments as well.

Comment: `Realm.open({` That doesn't look like the correct way to open a Realm in react. I believe it would be  `const realm = await Realm.open({`. I could be incorrect as I am not a React expert.

Comment: Hi @Jay,  this code just to do a test. I'm not waiting for the async promise to resolve. I'm getting this error by calling Realm.open() function.

Comment: The code is a bit incomplete; does your code have this before attempting to access Realm? `Realm.copyBundledRealmFiles();`. Did you try accessing realm at the default location? Does awaiting make a difference `realm = await Realm.open({`